# div width 100% overflow-x

Tags: css, width

Как реализовать прокрутку при `div` `width = 100%;` ? 
При установке ширины блока в пикселях все отлично работает.

```html
<div style="width:100%; overflow-x: scroll;">
  <table width="100000px;">
    <tr><td style="background:#f00">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: И в чем вопрос? У блока `width:100%` и прокрутка есть.

Answer (score 2):

Добавьте вашей табличке высоту:

```html
<div style="width:100%; overflow-x: scroll;">
<table width="100000px;" height="20px;">
...
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Не помогает - тут работает, так как тут внешняя ширина задана в пикселях!

Comment: @user241653 я ничего не менял в вашем примере, просто добавил `height="20px;"`

Comment: Так оно из без высоты прекрасно работало

Comment: @vp_arth посмотрите историю правок

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно, чтобы таблица была минимум на ширину страницы? Тогда используйте следующий код:

```html
<div style="width:100%; overflow-x: auto;">
  <table style="min-width:100%;">
    <tr><td style="background:#f00">&nbsp;</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Если вы хотите задать ячейкам ширину, превышающую текущую ширину таблицы (чтобы растянуть ее), то либо измените их стиль display, либо добавьте внутрь ячеек блочный элемент с указанной шириной.

```html
<div style="width:100%; overflow-x: auto;">
  <table style="min-width:100%;">
    <tr><td style="background:#f00"><div style="width:1000px">&nbsp;</div></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```